Why doesn't Shor's algorithm suggest a fast classical algorithm?
I am reading (and quoting) Andrew Child's notes, and I'm trying to understand the HSP for abelian groups, and in particular why the quantum algorithm doesn't shed any light on a potential classical algorithm.
The quantum algorithm prepares the superposition $\frac{1}{\sqrt{|G|}}\sum_{x \in G}|x\rangle$, then computes the function in the second register $\frac{1}{\sqrt{|G|}}\sum_{x \in G}|x\rangle|f(x) \rangle$. Discarding the second register gives a coset state $|x+H\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{|H|}}\sum_{h \in H}|x+h\rangle$ since $f(x)$ is identical on cosets of $H$. Apply the QFT over $G$ to obtain $|\widehat{x+H}\rangle = \sqrt{\frac{|H|}{|G|}}\sum_{y \in \hat{G}}\chi_y(x)\chi_y(H)|y\rangle = \sqrt{\frac{|H|}{|G|}}\sum_{y: \chi_y(H)=1}\chi_y(x)|y\rangle$ where $\chi_y(H)=\frac{1}{|H|}\sum_{h \in H}\chi_y(h)$.
Next we measure in the computational basis to obtain a character $\chi_y$ that is trivial on the hidden subgroup $H$. Thus we only need to focus on elements $g$ such that $\chi_y(g)=1$. This is $\ker \chi_y = \{g \in G| \chi_y(g)=1\}$. Taking sufficiently many intersections of such kernels yields $H$ with high probability.
In Simon's problem (the HSP with $G=(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n$ and $H=\{0,s\}$ for some $s \in G$) it's possible to show that any classical algorithm must make exponentially many (in $n$) queries to the hiding function. A proof relies on having a large number of trivially intersecting subgroups of $G$.
He also states "The gist of the argument is that, since the set $S$ is unstructured, we can do no better than querying random group elements so long as we do not know two elements $x,y$ for which $f(x) = f(y)$."
For the case $G=\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$, $H=\mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z}$, $S=(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^\times$ (factoring) are there not a large number of trivially intersecting subgroups, so that the above argument does not apply, and we can't rule out a classical algorithm? It also seems like one could equip $S$ with more structure by embedding it into a field like $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Surely if we have two numbers $x,y$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$ where $f=a^x\bmod N$ then we would be well on our way to factoring $N$? The trouble is, how do you find such collisions?

Shor algorithm has also a classical version. However, on a classical computer a complexity of period finding is also exponential. So, this prevents us from using Shor classically. On the other hand, this does not imply that there can be classical or even quantum factoring algorithm with lower complexity than in case of the Shor.

@MarkSpinelli Right, then $f(x)f(y)^{-1} = a^{x-y} = 1,\text{mod},N$. Collisions seem hard to find; I was only objecting to $S$ being unstructured;. Upon closer inspection, there are very "quantum" steps that are hard to reproduce. Take $\alpha$ an $N^{th}$ root of unity in $F_q$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Then redefine $f(x) = \alpha^{a^x}$. This is still a periodic function with period $r$. I can even write down the (classical) FT $(Ff)_i = \sum_j \alpha^{ij+a^j}$. The problem is I can't make a "coset state" using tensor products and discarding the auxiliary register. It exponential to do this sum.
